# Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005) в чем проблема?

Tags: python, pyqt5, исключения, keyboardhook

У меня следующая проблема: я использую библиотеку *PyQt5* и *keyboard* это код функции которая лежит после класса окна приложения

```
def take_key(key):  # функция которая будет вызываться каждое нажатие клавиши за счет keyboard.hook
    global key_last
    if key.event_type == "up":
        key_last = str(key.name)
        print(key_last)
        programmDKB.show_key_NOW(key.name)  # Строчка из-за которой ошибка
keyboard.hook(take_key)
```

это функция `show_key_NOW`, которая лежит в классе окна приложения

```
    def show_key_NOW(self, key):
        print(key + key_last)
        self.key_show.setText(key)
```

также есть `except_hook` но он не работает когда программа падает из-за попытки отобразить нажатую клавишу, в остальных случаях работает
Приложение падает с этой ошибкой `Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)`
Полный код программы здесь https://disk.yandex.ru/d/iBRt5fFRCjpOCg

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: https://youtu.be/zB1YkBwPoP8 извините за долгий ответ

Comment: sorry, я у вас спрашивал о минимально-воспроизводимом примере, который надо опубликовать в теле вопроса, а не ссылкой. И второе, чтобы получить реальную ошибку - запускайте ваше приложение из консоли/терминала/CMD